# Any other software for installing .exe files in ubuntu except wine

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I've tried wine software to install .exe files in my ubuntu 12.10 os but many times it is not able to install the software appropriately or if installed then the windows software file does not works properly. So can anyone suggest me some other software in ubuntu which will helps me to install and run windows software in my ubuntu 12.10. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There's [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/), which is basically a paid, stable version of Wine with officially supported programs and customer support. It has a wider range of software support, but like Wine, it can't support everything. I can also suggest running Windows in a virtual machine.

Comment: No freeware software which will helps me to install windows file in linux. Yup, i have installed windows xp on virtual box in my ubuntu to run my windows file..:)

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, you have to use WINE in some form.  One thing you might want to try is [Play On Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps.html), which isn't just for games as the name seems to imply.  Also, have you looked at the [Wine app DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/)?  That will tell you general reports about your software's compatibility.

Comment: I have not looked yet at wibe app DB and also i will try to put my hands on play on linux software.

Answer (score 1):

For [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) apps you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu).